# Java Heap Dump analysis

Tags: jvm

> Hi Friends,
>
> I need some help in understanding which got generated by our
>   application. I facing such scenario for the first time and need your
>   input and suggestion.
>
> As we are migrating our 32 bit application to 64 bit we are currently
>   facing the issue where our application in unable to launch.
>
> One of our bat file generates the Heap dump in a path like this:
>
> run.bat:

```
@echo off

REM This script is called to run all products.

if not "%MM_USE_CLASSPATH%" == "true" goto noclasspath
goto execute

:noclasspath
set CLASSPATH=%INSTDIR%\classes;%INSTDIR%\jar\*;%INSTDIR%\jar\custom\*

:execute
REM set java specific arguments
set JVM_ARGS=-classpath "%CLASSPATH%"
REM If we get out of memory allow a dump file to be created
set JVM_ARGS=%JVM_ARGS% -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
REM use TEMP for heap dumps, users may not have access to the install location
set JVM_ARGS=%JVM_ARGS% -XX:HeapDumpPath=%TEMP%/
REM on an out of memory error, kill the client.
set JVM_ARGS=%JVM_ARGS% -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="taskkill /F /PID %%p"
REM set error log file location
set JVM_ARGS=%JVM_ARGS% -XX:ErrorFile=%TEMP%/mm_hs_err_pid%%p.log
REM Install the Manager generic AWT Exception handler
set JVM_ARGS=%JVM_ARGS% -Dsun.awt.exception.handler=com.osm.exception.AwtReplacementExceptionHandler
REM Define memory limits, initial java heap size and the maximum java heap size 
set JVM_ARGS=%JVM_ARGS% -Xms50m -Xmx256m
REM Enable PTC laf window decoration (or when false use OS decoration)
set JVM_ARGS=%JVM_ARGS% -Duse.ptc.window.decoration=true
REM uncomment the next line to enable anti aliased fonts
REM set JVM_ARGS=%JVM_ARGS% -Dswing.aatext=true
REM use manager look and feel
REM set JVM_ARGS=%JVM_ARGS% -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.osm.ui.laf.xplookandfeel.XPLookAndFeel
set JVM_ARGS=%JVM_ARGS% -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.osm.ui.laf.ptc.PtcLaf

if not "%DEBUG_MM%" == "true" goto default
echo Running %PRODUCT_NAME% with Debug Support
REM if JDKDIR is set, we run with a debuggable Java runtime
if "%JDKDIR%" == "" goto rundebugclient
set JAVA_EXE=%JDKDIR%\jre\bin\java.exe
echo Using JDK executable %JAVA_EXE%
:rundebugclient
cmd.exe /C start "Running %PRODUCT_NAME% with Debug Support" /WAIT "%JAVA_EXE%" -Xnoagent -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_shmem,address=mm,server=y,suspend=n %JVM_ARGS% %DEBUG_JVM_ARGS% com.osm.datamgmt.DataManager %PRODUCT_CODE% "%CONFIGDIR%" "%INSTDIR%\"
goto ending

:default
echo Running %PRODUCT_NAME%
REM Redirect output to nul as we may log things to the console logger which has nowhere to go
"%JAVA_EXE%" %JVM_ARGS% com.osm.datamgmt.DataManager %PRODUCT_CODE% "%CONFIGDIR%" "%INSTDIR%\" > NUL 2>&1

:ending
```

Now the result in the heap dump is which I am unable to understand:

```
 #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007fff4bd938d0, pid=6920, tid=0x0000000000002754
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_152-b16) (build 1.8.0_152-b16)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.152-b16 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libpdm.dll+0x838d0]  pdm_gv_type+0x0
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000001a5fa000):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=10068, stack(0x000000001c350000,0x000000001c450000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x000000004c0c78e0

Registers:
RAX=0x000000004c0c78d8, RBX=0x0000000025320ee0, RCX=0x000000004c0c78d8, RDX=0x000000001c44de70
RSP=0x000000001c44de08, RBP=0x000000001c44deb0, RSI=0x0000000025320ee0, RDI=0x000000001c44de40
R8 =0x0000000000000032, R9 =0x00000000fbda24f8, R10=0x0000000000000068, R11=0x0000000070d624d8
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x000000001c44e0a8, R14=0x000000001c44dea0, R15=0x000000001a5fa000
RIP=0x00007fff4bd938d0, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000001c44de08)
0x000000001c44de08:   00007fff7a7d3fc9 000000001a5fa1f8
0x000000001c44de18:   000000001c44de70 cccccccccccccccc
0x000000001c44de28:   cccccccccccccccc cccccccccccccccc
0x000000001c44de38:   cccccccccccccccc 0000000000000fd3
0x000000001c44de48:   000000000553cad4 000000001a5fa1f8
0x000000001c44de58:   000000001c44dea0 000000001c44de70
0x000000001c44de68:   0000000000000000 00000000fbda24f8
0x000000001c44de78:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001c44de88:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001c44de98:   0000000000000000 00000000f0c044d8
0x000000001c44dea8:   0000000000000000 000000001c44e108
0x000000001c44deb8:   000000000554ba74 0000000000000000
0x000000001c44dec8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001c44ded8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001c44dee8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001c44def8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007fff4bd938d0)
0x00007fff4bd938b0:   ff ff 48 89 0d 5f 44 35 00 49 8b d1 e9 8f fe ff
0x00007fff4bd938c0:   ff cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc
0x00007fff4bd938d0:   0f b6 41 08 c3 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc
0x00007fff4bd938e0:   48 89 5c 24 08 57 48 83 ec 20 48 8b da e8 1e 78 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x000000004c0c78d8 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000025320ee0 is pointing into metadata
RCX=0x000000004c0c78d8 is an unknown value
RDX=0x000000001c44de70 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001a5fa000
RSP=0x000000001c44de08 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001a5fa000
RBP=0x000000001c44deb0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001a5fa000
RSI=0x0000000025320ee0 is pointing into metadata
RDI=0x000000001c44de40 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001a5fa000
R8 =0x0000000000000032 is an unknown value
R9 =0x00000000fbda24f8 is an oop
com.osm.biz.pdm$ptr32 
 - klass: 'com/osm/biz/pdm$ptr32'
R10=0x0000000000000068 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000070d624d8 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x000000001c44e0a8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001a5fa000
R14=0x000000001c44dea0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001a5fa000
R15=0x000000001a5fa000 is a thread


Stack: [0x000000001c350000,0x000000001c450000],  sp=0x000000001c44de08,  free space=1015k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libpdm.dll+0x838d0]  pdm_gv_type+0x0

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 2323  com.osm.biz.pdm._gv_type(Lcom/osm/biz/pdm$ptr;)I (0 bytes) @ 0x000000000553ca52 [0x000000000553ca00+0x52]
J 2322 C1 com.osm.biz.pdm.gv_type(Lcom/osm/biz/pdm$ptr;)I (54 bytes) @ 0x000000000554ba74 [0x000000000554b720+0x354]
J 2321 C1 com.osm.biz.GenVal.toJava(Lcom/osm/biz/pdm$ptr;)Ljava/lang/Object; (141 bytes) @ 0x0000000005547b4c [0x0000000005547ae0+0x6c]
j  com.osm.biz.WMDBObject.isValueDifferent(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z+22
j  com.osm.biz.WMDBObject.setCacheValue(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+44
j  com.osm.datamgmt.biz.RecentlyLoadedList.updateValue(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+27
j  com.osm.datamgmt.biz.RecentlyLoadedList.setMaxNumber(I)V+23
j  com.osm.datamgmt.biz.RecentlyLoadedList.createNewRecentlyUsedListForUser()Lcom/osm/datamgmt/biz/RecentlyLoadedList;+26
j  com.osm.datamgmt.biz.RecentlyLoadedList.getInstance()Lcom/osm/datamgmt/biz/RecentlyLoadedList;+35
j  com.osm.datamgmt.ui.ManagerPanel.init(Lcom/osm/ui/UIConfig;)V+0
j  com.osm.datamgmt.ui.ManagerPanel.<init>()V+39
j  com.osm.datamgmt.ui.ManagerPanel.constructNewManagerPanel()Lcom/osm/datamgmt/ui/ManagerPanel;+4
j  com.osm.datamgmt.DataManager$2.run()V+0
J 1909 C1 java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch()V (69 bytes) @ 0x000000000542e64c [0x000000000542e500+0x14c]
J 1987 C1 java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V (149 bytes) @ 0x0000000005466684 [0x0000000005464bc0+0x1ac4]
J 1985 C1 java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Void; (60 bytes) @ 0x0000000005461acc [0x00000000054618c0+0x20c]
J 1984 C1 java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Object; (5 bytes) @ 0x000000000545e9cc [0x000000000545e940+0x8c]
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J 685  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (0 bytes) @ 0x00000000050b08e6 [0x00000000050b0880+0x66]
J 1662 C1 java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V (80 bytes) @ 0x0000000005396f04 [0x0000000005396580+0x984]
J 1988 C1 java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)V (295 bytes) @ 0x000000000546c134 [0x000000000546a480+0x1cb4]
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V+35
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000019e5d800 JavaThread "MesgBdcstCheckerThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14676, stack(0x0000000027740000,0x0000000027840000)]
  0x0000000019e5e000 JavaThread "CheckForUpdates" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1080, stack(0x0000000027640000,0x0000000027740000)]
  0x0000000019e5c000 JavaThread "Keep-Alive-Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=17532, stack(0x0000000027540000,0x0000000027640000)]
  0x0000000019e5a800 JavaThread "DisconnectOnIdleThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3320, stack(0x0000000025a70000,0x0000000025b70000)]
  0x000000001a5e9800 JavaThread "D3D Screen Updater" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13368, stack(0x0000000024320000,0x0000000024420000)]
  0x000000001a04c000 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18400, stack(0x00000000225a0000,0x00000000226a0000)]
=>0x000000001a5fa000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=10068, stack(0x000000001c350000,0x000000001c450000)]
  0x0000000018c31000 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9972, stack(0x0000000019be0000,0x0000000019ce0000)]
  0x0000000018c2f000 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=19308, stack(0x0000000019ae0000,0x0000000019be0000)]
  0x0000000018c2e000 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1076, stack(0x00000000199e0000,0x0000000019ae0000)]
  0x00000000189b9800 JavaThread "Keep Alive" [_thread_blocked, id=8220, stack(0x00000000195a0000,0x00000000196a0000)]
  0x00000000189b8800 JavaThread "Deadlock Detector Thread ->C:\Users\vkarn\AppData\Local\Temp\mm_deadlock_8279648827737022103.log" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10568, stack(0x00000000194a0000,0x00000000195a0000)]
  0x0000000017c42800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3252, stack(0x0000000018760000,0x0000000018860000)]
  0x0000000017bab000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13548, stack(0x0000000018660000,0x0000000018760000)]
  0x0000000017ba6000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9352, stack(0x0000000018560000,0x0000000018660000)]
  0x0000000017ba3000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6828, stack(0x0000000018460000,0x0000000018560000)]
  0x0000000017ba1000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18104, stack(0x0000000018360000,0x0000000018460000)]
  0x0000000017b9f000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9208, stack(0x0000000018260000,0x0000000018360000)]
  0x0000000017b9e000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13948, stack(0x0000000018160000,0x0000000018260000)]
  0x0000000017b90800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12632, stack(0x0000000017f70000,0x0000000018070000)]
  0x0000000015cac800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10236, stack(0x0000000017a70000,0x0000000017b70000)]
  0x0000000004c33800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=6840, stack(0x0000000003320000,0x0000000003420000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000015ca9800 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000017970000,0x0000000017a70000] [id=17756]
  0x0000000017c5d800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000018860000,0x0000000018960000] [id=17884]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 62464K, used 19199K [0x00000000fab00000, 0x00000000fff00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 51200K, 37% used [0x00000000fab00000,0x00000000fbdbff78,0x00000000fdd00000)
  from space 11264K, 0% used [0x00000000fdd00000,0x00000000fdd00000,0x00000000fe800000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000ff480000,0x00000000ff480000,0x00000000fff00000)
 ParOldGen       total 39424K, used 15676K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f2680000, 0x00000000fab00000)
  object space 39424K, 39% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f0f4f360,0x00000000f2680000)
 Metaspace       used 22124K, capacity 22320K, committed 22576K, reserved 1069056K
  class space    used 2925K, capacity 2991K, committed 3072K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x00000000141b0000,0x0000000014240000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000013a30000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x0000000070d70860
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000014a40000, 0x0000000014e40000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000014e40000, 0x0000000015240000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000be0000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=8225Kb max_used=8266Kb free=237534Kb
 bounds [0x0000000004df0000, 0x0000000005620000, 0x0000000013df0000]
 total_blobs=3027 nmethods=2458 adapters=481
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 15.716 Thread 0x0000000017ba6000 2448   !   4       com.osm.biz.WMLtab::getColumnIndex (110 bytes)
Event: 15.726 Thread 0x0000000017ba6000 nmethod 2448 0x00000000055cd2d0 code [0x00000000055cd4a0, 0x00000000055cdfd8]
Event: 15.726 Thread 0x0000000017ba6000 2446       4       java.lang.ref.Finalizer::register (10 bytes)
Event: 15.728 Thread 0x0000000017ba6000 nmethod 2446 0x0000000004eefd90 code [0x0000000004eeff00, 0x0000000004ef0278]
Event: 15.728 Thread 0x0000000017ba6000 2477       4       java.util.ArrayList::<init> (12 bytes)
Event: 15.728 Thread 0x0000000017ba6000 nmethod 2477 0x000000000554c4d0 code [0x000000000554c600, 0x000000000554c678]
Event: 15.728 Thread 0x0000000017ba6000 2454       4       java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap::casTabAt (20 bytes)
Event: 15.729 Thread 0x0000000017ba6000 nmethod 2454 0x0000000005532850 code [0x0000000005532980, 0x00000000055329f8]
Event: 15.752 Thread 0x0000000017ba3000 nmethod 2428 0x00000000055e9310 code [0x00000000055e9aa0, 0x00000000055f2268]
Event: 15.771 Thread 0x0000000017ba1000 nmethod 2401 0x00000000055fed90 code [0x00000000055ff440, 0x0000000005606ae0]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 4.960 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=4 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 14848K, used 14832K [0x00000000fab00000, 0x00000000fc800000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 12800K, 100% used [0x00000000fab00000,0x00000000fb780000,0x00000000fb780000)
  from space 2048K, 99% used [0x00000000fb780000,0x00000000fb97c040,0x00000000fb980000)
  to   space 2048K, 0% used [0x00000000fc600000,0x00000000fc600000,0x00000000fc800000)
 ParOldGen       total 34304K, used 7767K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f2180000, 0x00000000fab00000)
  object space 34304K, 22% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f0795e68,0x00000000f2180000)
 Metaspace       used 18503K, capacity 18706K, committed 18944K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 2409K, capacity 2476K, committed 2560K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 4.965 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=4 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 27648K, used 2016K [0x00000000fab00000, 0x00000000fc800000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 25600K, 0% used [0x00000000fab00000,0x00000000fab00000,0x00000000fc400000)
  from space 2048K, 98% used [0x00000000fc600000,0x00000000fc7f8020,0x00000000fc800000)
  to   space 2048K, 0% used [0x00000000fc400000,0x00000000fc400000,0x00000000fc600000)
 ParOldGen       total 34304K, used 12218K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f2180000, 0x00000000fab00000)
  object space 34304K, 35% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f0bee810,0x00000000f2180000)
 Metaspace       used 18503K, capacity 18706K, committed 18944K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 2409K, capacity 2476K, committed 2560K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 15.272 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=5 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 27648K, used 27616K [0x00000000fab00000, 0x00000000fc800000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 25600K, 100% used [0x00000000fab00000,0x00000000fc400000,0x00000000fc400000)
  from space 2048K, 98% used [0x00000000fc600000,0x00000000fc7f8020,0x00000000fc800000)
  to   space 2048K, 0% used [0x00000000fc400000,0x00000000fc400000,0x00000000fc600000)
 ParOldGen       total 34304K, used 12218K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f2180000, 0x00000000fab00000)
  object space 34304K, 35% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f0bee810,0x00000000f2180000)
 Metaspace       used 20817K, capacity 21066K, committed 21248K, reserved 1067008K
  class space    used 2671K, capacity 2766K, committed 2816K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 15.278 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=5 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 27648K, used 2048K [0x00000000fab00000, 0x00000000ff300000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 25600K, 0% used [0x00000000fab00000,0x00000000fab00000,0x00000000fc400000)
  from space 2048K, 100% used [0x00000000fc400000,0x00000000fc600000,0x00000000fc600000)
  to   space 11264K, 0% used [0x00000000fe800000,0x00000000fe800000,0x00000000ff300000)
 ParOldGen       total 34304K, used 18848K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f2180000, 0x00000000fab00000)
  object space 34304K, 54% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f12681e0,0x00000000f2180000)
 Metaspace       used 20817K, capacity 21066K, committed 21248K, reserved 1067008K
  class space    used 2671K, capacity 2766K, committed 2816K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 15.307 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=6 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 27648K, used 27648K [0x00000000fab00000, 0x00000000ff300000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 25600K, 100% used [0x00000000fab00000,0x00000000fc400000,0x00000000fc400000)
  from space 2048K, 100% used [0x00000000fc400000,0x00000000fc600000,0x00000000fc600000)
  to   space 11264K, 0% used [0x00000000fe800000,0x00000000fe800000,0x00000000ff300000)
 ParOldGen       total 34304K, used 18848K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f2180000, 0x00000000fab00000)
  object space 34304K, 54% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f12681e0,0x00000000f2180000)
 Metaspace       used 20820K, capacity 21066K, committed 21248K, reserved 1067008K
  class space    used 2671K, capacity 2766K, committed 2816K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 15.312 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=6 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 62464K, used 3344K [0x00000000fab00000, 0x00000000ff300000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 51200K, 0% used [0x00000000fab00000,0x00000000fab00000,0x00000000fdd00000)
  from space 11264K, 29% used [0x00000000fe800000,0x00000000feb44010,0x00000000ff300000)
  to   space 11264K, 0% used [0x00000000fdd00000,0x00000000fdd00000,0x00000000fe800000)
 ParOldGen       total 34304K, used 18856K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f2180000, 0x00000000fab00000)
  object space 34304K, 54% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f126a1e0,0x00000000f2180000)
 Metaspace       used 20820K, capacity 21066K, committed 21248K, reserved 1067008K
  class space    used 2671K, capacity 2766K, committed 2816K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 15.390 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=7 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 62464K, used 30103K [0x00000000fab00000, 0x00000000ff300000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 51200K, 52% used [0x00000000fab00000,0x00000000fc521c90,0x00000000fdd00000)
  from space 11264K, 29% used [0x00000000fe800000,0x00000000feb44010,0x00000000ff300000)
  to   space 11264K, 0% used [0x00000000fdd00000,0x00000000fdd00000,0x00000000fe800000)
 ParOldGen       total 34304K, used 18856K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f2180000, 0x00000000fab00000)
  object space 34304K, 54% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f126a1e0,0x00000000f2180000)
 Metaspace       used 20971K, capacity 21168K, committed 21296K, reserved 1069056K
  class space    used 2723K, capacity 2799K, committed 2816K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 15.394 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=7 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 62464K, used 3360K [0x00000000fab00000, 0x00000000fff00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 51200K, 0% used [0x00000000fab00000,0x00000000fab00000,0x00000000fdd00000)
  from space 11264K, 29% used [0x00000000fdd00000,0x00000000fe0480c0,0x00000000fe800000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000ff480000,0x00000000ff480000,0x00000000fff00000)
 ParOldGen       total 34304K, used 19604K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f2180000, 0x00000000fab00000)
  object space 34304K, 57% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f1325220,0x00000000f2180000)
 Metaspace       used 20971K, capacity 21168K, committed 21296K, reserved 1069056K
  class space    used 2723K, capacity 2799K, committed 2816K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 15.394 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=8 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 62464K, used 3360K [0x00000000fab00000, 0x00000000fff00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 51200K, 0% used [0x00000000fab00000,0x00000000fab00000,0x00000000fdd00000)
  from space 11264K, 29% used [0x00000000fdd00000,0x00000000fe0480c0,0x00000000fe800000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000ff480000,0x00000000ff480000,0x00000000fff00000)
 ParOldGen       total 34304K, used 19604K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f2180000, 0x00000000fab00000)
  object space 34304K, 57% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f1325220,0x00000000f2180000)
 Metaspace       used 20971K, capacity 21168K, committed 21296K, reserved 1069056K
  class space    used 2723K, capacity 2799K, committed 2816K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 15.451 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=8 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 62464K, used 0K [0x00000000fab00000, 0x00000000fff00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 51200K, 0% used [0x00000000fab00000,0x00000000fab00000,0x00000000fdd00000)
  from space 11264K, 0% used [0x00000000fdd00000,0x00000000fdd00000,0x00000000fe800000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000ff480000,0x00000000ff480000,0x00000000fff00000)
 ParOldGen       total 39424K, used 15676K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f2680000, 0x00000000fab00000)
  object space 39424K, 39% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f0f4f360,0x00000000f2680000)
 Metaspace       used 20971K, capacity 21168K, committed 21296K, reserved 1069056K
  class space    used 2723K, capacity 2799K, committed 2816K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 4.876 Thread 0x0000000019e60800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000052412f4 method=org.jdom2.ContentList$FilterList.resync(I)I @ 161
Event: 10.597 Thread 0x0000000019e60800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000054516ec method=java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(I)Z @ 2
Event: 10.602 Thread 0x0000000019e60800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000052a3c60 method=java.lang.Integer.valueOf(I)Ljava/lang/Integer; @ 3
Event: 10.604 Thread 0x0000000019e60800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000054516ec method=java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(I)Z @ 2
Event: 10.605 Thread 0x0000000019e60800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000054516ec method=java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(I)Z @ 2
Event: 10.606 Thread 0x0000000019e60800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000054516ec method=java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(I)Z @ 2
Event: 10.611 Thread 0x0000000019e60800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000000000513fa70 method=java.util.LinkedHashMap.afterNodeInsertion(Z)V @ 1
Event: 10.616 Thread 0x0000000019e60800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000000000503eb18 method=java.util.HashMap.putVal(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 203
Event: 10.616 Thread 0x0000000019e60800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000005041040 method=java.util.HashMap.putVal(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 203
Event: 15.234 Thread 0x0000000019e60800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000005200db4 method=java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 138

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 10.618 Thread 0x0000000019e60800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x00000000fb07c6b0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u152\9742\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 10.619 Thread 0x0000000019e60800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x00000000fb07d938) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u152\9742\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 10.619 Thread 0x0000000019e60800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x00000000fb07f2b0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u152\9742\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 10.623 Thread 0x0000000019e60800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x00000000fb0a48f0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u152\9742\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 10.625 Thread 0x0000000019e60800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x00000000fb0b29d0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u152\9742\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 15.147 Thread 0x0000000019e60800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x00000000fb127f28) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u152\9742\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1185]
Event: 15.148 Thread 0x0000000019e60800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x00000000fb1288c8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u152\9742\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1185]
Event: 15.166 Thread 0x0000000019e60800 Exception <a 'com/osm/exception/WMKernelException'> (0x00000000fb2ec740) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u152\9742\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 15.510 Thread 0x0000000019e5d800 Exception <a 'com/osm/exception/WMKernelException'> (0x00000000fb4864a0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u152\9742\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 15.513 Thread 0x0000000004c33800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassCastException'> (0x00000000fb404ee0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u152\9742\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]

Events (10 events):
Event: 15.799 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 15.799 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 15.800 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 15.800 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 15.816 loading class com/osm/biz/EventHandler
Event: 15.816 loading class com/osm/biz/EventHandler done
Event: 15.818 loading class com/osm/event/WMNewWMObjectEvent
Event: 15.818 loading class com/osm/event/WMNewWMObjectEvent done
Event: 15.819 loading class com/osm/biz/AttributePropertyCache
Event: 15.819 loading class com/osm/biz/AttributePropertyCache done
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a heap dump. It is a JVM crash dump which got written when your running JVM crashed.

It is not just heap information, it shows much more information about what was happening at the time when the crash happened, e.g. various threads that existed, stack frames in the current running thread etc. It also has information at the contents of the heap around the time of the crash.

See these links for interpreting the information available in the crash dump file:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/dumpfile.html

http://jagadesh4java.blogspot.in/2014/09/analyzing-jvm-crash.html